# Given a start and end date, most efficient way to generate all weeks in between?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have two columns, 'start_date' and 'end_date', which could be a wide range of dates, from just one day (no difference between dates) to 18 months apart.  The API I am working with only wants 7 days in between dates, however, so I'd like to parse out the date ranges supplied by a user into unique rows for every 7 days (and not exceed the supplied end date).

I successfully achieved this with a udf, but I'm curious if there is a more efficient way I didn't think of.  This is the dataframe I'm starting out with:

```
foo   start_date   end_date
foo1  2017-08-01   2017-09-01
```

I transformed it into this:

```
foo   start_date   end_date
foo1  2017-08-01   2017-08-07
foo1  2017-08-08   2017-08-14
foo1  2017-08-15   2017-08-21
foo1  2017-08-22   2017-08-28
foo1  2017-08-29   2017-09-01
```

This is my code.  It works, and is fine for the purposes of my data since I'm only splitting up to ~40 rows at a time...  but the solution feels exceptionally hamfisted.  I'm curious if there's a much more efficient approach.

```
def list_of_weeks(start,end):
  if start == end:
    return start
  else:
    start, end = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d'), datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')
    dates = [start]
    curr_date = start
    end = end - timedelta(7)
    while curr_date <= end:
      curr_date += timedelta(7)
      dates.append(curr_date)
    dates = ','.join([x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in dates])
    return dates

end = df.select('end_date').collect()[0][0]
end = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')

list_of_weeks_udf = udf(list_of_weeks)
df = (df.withColumn('start_date', split(list_of_weeks_udf('start_date','end_date'), ','))
            .withColumn('start_date', explode('start_date'))
            .withColumn('start_date', to_date('start_date'))
            .withColumn('end_date', date_add('start_date', 6))
            .withColumn('end_date', when(col('end_date')>end, end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).otherwise(col('end_date'))))
```

Comment: I've updated my answer now fixing the last end_date and using df for outputting

Answer (score 2):

This is using [pandas' date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html):

```
import pandas

start, end = '2017-08-01', '2017-09-01'
d1 = pandas.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='7D')
d2 = d1.shift(6, freq='d')
# fix end date (make sure latest end_date it doesn't go over end_date)
d2 = list(d2)[:-1] + [min(d2[-1], pandas.Timestamp(end))]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=dict(foo=['foo1']*len(d1), start_date=d1, end_date=d2), 
    columns=('foo', 'start_date', 'end_date'))

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Prints:

```
foo start_date   end_date
foo1 2017-08-01 2017-08-07
foo1 2017-08-08 2017-08-14
foo1 2017-08-15 2017-08-21
foo1 2017-08-22 2017-08-28
foo1 2017-08-29 2017-09-01
```

Btw, the justification seems slightly off due to `index=False`, see [this open pandas bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13032)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the whole question be here is an easy way to generate your columns given a start and end date.

```
import pandas as pd
start = pd.date_range(start="2017-8-01", end="2017-9-1", freq="7D")
end = start + pd.Timedelta(weeks=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v=(df.end_date-df.start_date).dt.days[0]//7
s2=s1[1:].shift(-1,freq='D').append(pd.Index(df.end_date))
s1=pd.date_range(start=df.start_date[0],periods=v+1,freq='7D')  
pd.DataFrame({'foo':df.foo.repeat(v+1),'start_date':s1,'end_date':s2})
Out[241]: 
    end_date   foo start_date
0 2017-08-07  foo1 2017-08-01
0 2017-08-14  foo1 2017-08-08
0 2017-08-21  foo1 2017-08-15
0 2017-08-28  foo1 2017-08-22
0 2017-09-01  foo1 2017-08-29
```