# How to find stock prices for the last 2 years in 1m intervals using a for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, analytics, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance

new to Python here. I have 7 assets. I have found the daily adjusted close for the last 2 years. However, I want the data minute by minute. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def dl_data(i):
    years = 2
    end = dt.datetime.today()
    start = end - dt.timedelta(365*years) 
    tickers = ["SBUX", "MCD", "CMG", "WEN", "DPZ", "YUM", "DENN"]
    return(yf.download(tickers, start, end)['Adj Close'])

data3 = yf.download(tickers, period='7d', interval='1m')['Adj Close']

for i in range(1,504): 
    data3 = data3.append(dl_data(i))
```

Python only allows 1m intervals for a period of 7 days, otherwise you get an error message. So, I have decided to use a loop to append it to the original data set. However, when I write *data3.head()* after the loop runs, the earliest it goes back is November 8, 2021. My understanding is that *for i in range(1,504)* performs the loop for the last 504 days, correct? How else can this be done?

Comment: As far as I know, you can get data at 1 minute intervals only for the last 7 days, but not for the rest of the past. Have you been able to get data at one-minute intervals in the past other than the last seven days?

Comment: Nope, I haven't been able to do this yet. My professor told me it could be done with a loop though.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot fetch more than 7 days of 1m interval data, within 30 days. Your professor is wrong.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get stock data in a two-hour interval rather than just one?

Answer (score 2):

`yfinance` does not allow you to download historical data on the 1-minute chart greater than 30 days old. And only allows you to download them in 7-day chunks.

Below is the error you would get if you tried:

```bash
1 Failed download:
- EURUSD=X: 1m data not available for startTime=1654387200 and endTime=1654905600. The requested range must be within the last 30 days.
```

While I can't answer your question fully due to the `yfinance` limitation, I can answer it to give you up to 30 days worth of 1m data. This is how I do this if I am forced to use yfinance. I usually use something else like `alpaca` or `binance` due to these limitations.

## First start by making a dataframe with date ranges

```py
import pandas as pd

TODAY = pd.to_datetime("today").date()
START = (TODAY - pd.DateOffset(days=29)).date()

# Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131963/16051077
d1 = pd.date_range(start=START, end=TODAY, freq="7D")
d2 = d1.shift(6, freq="d")
# fix end date (make sure latest end_date it doesn't go over end_date)
d2 = list(d2)[:-1] + [min(d2[-1], pd.Timestamp(TODAY))]

dates = pd.DataFrame(
    data=dict(start_date=d1, end_date=d2), columns=("start_date", "end_date")
)
```

### Output:

```bash
    start_date    end_date
0   2022-06-06  2022-06-12
1   2022-06-13  2022-06-19
2   2022-06-20  2022-06-26
3   2022-06-27  2022-07-03
4   2022-07-04  2022-07-05
```

## Use `dates` DataFrame in for loop

```py
import yfinance as yf

df_list = []
for i in dates.index:
    start = dates.at[i, "start_date"]
    end = dates.at[i, "end_date"]

    tickers = ["TSLA", "MSFT", "AMZN"]

    df = yf.download(tickers, start=start, end=end, interval="1m")["Adj Close"]
    df_list.append(df)

history = pd.concat(df_list)
```

### Output:

***Note:*** *Data doesn't include all dates due to market holiday.*

```bash
[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed

                                  AMZN        MSFT        TSLA
2022-06-06 09:30:00-04:00   125.574501  273.179993  731.722900
2022-06-06 09:31:00-04:00   125.190002  273.500000  730.260010
2022-06-06 09:32:00-04:00   124.559998  273.190002  727.300110
2022-06-06 09:33:00-04:00   124.167503  273.519989  726.155029
2022-06-06 09:34:00-04:00   124.719902  273.220001  723.989990
... ... ... ...
2022-07-01 15:56:00-04:00   109.489998  259.029999  680.890015
2022-07-01 15:57:00-04:00   109.389999  259.079987  680.869995
2022-07-01 15:58:00-04:00   109.474998  259.369995  680.710022
2022-07-01 15:59:00-04:00   109.550003  259.539001  681.890015
2022-07-01 16:00:00-04:00   109.559998  259.579987  681.789978
7409 rows × 3 columns
```

## Full Code:

```python
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

TODAY = pd.to_datetime("today").date()
START = (TODAY - pd.DateOffset(days=29)).date()

# Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131963/16051077
d1 = pd.date_range(start=START, end=TODAY, freq="7D")
d2 = d1.shift(6, freq="d")
# fix end date (make sure latest end_date it doesn't go over end_date)
d2 = list(d2)[:-1] + [min(d2[-1], pd.Timestamp(TODAY))]

dates = pd.DataFrame(
    data=dict(start_date=d1, end_date=d2), columns=("start_date", "end_date")
)

df_list = []
for i in dates.index:
    start = dates.at[i, "start_date"]
    end = dates.at[i, "end_date"]

    tickers = ["TSLA", "MSFT", "AMZN"]

    df = yf.download(tickers, start=start, end=end, interval="1m")["Adj Close"]
    df_list.append(df)

history = pd.concat(df_list)
```